# How to delete a debezium connector

Tags: debezium

How can I delete a debezium connector. I am following this tutorial
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html and I see the way to register a connector but couldn't figure out how to delete / update a connector.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "inventory-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "debezium", "database.password": "dbz", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.include.list": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory" } }'
```

Can you also please point to me to the documentation page where deleting and updating a connector is mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`debezium connector` is a standard connector which you plug in to kafka connet framework. The Kafka Connect framework support several REST commands in order to interact with it.

For delete you submit DELETE request

```
curl -i -X DELETE localhost:8083/connectors/inventory-connector/
```

To update configuration you submit PUT request with the new configuration

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/inventory-connector/config -d '{ "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "debezium", "database.password": "dbz", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.include.list": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory" }'
```

Further REST API instructions

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html

Comment: When you delete connector, you can not recreate debezium with same name.

Comment: @prakashpoudel I think this is because deleting the connector doesn't delete the replication slot (in Postgres) and you can't have 2 slots with the same name.